# Recharts - Reversed Vertical Barchart with Rounded Corners have Inverted Ends

Tags: javascript, html, css, recharts

I want to create a bar chart with rounded bars that looks like this, but have the bars in reverse

[image]

But after adding the **reversed** prop to the **XAxis** component, it becomes like this

[image]

Here is my code i did from one of the examples in Recharts

```js
const {BarChart, Bar, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend} = Recharts;
const data = [
      {name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400},
      {name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210},
      {name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290},
      {name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000},
      {name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181},
];

const SimpleBarChart = React.createClass({
   render () {
     return (
       <BarChart width={ 600 } height={ 400 } data={ data } maxBarSize={ 20 } layout={ 'vertical' }>
         <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
         <XAxis type={ 'number' } orientation={ 'top' } reversed />
         <YAxis type={ 'category' } orientation={ 'right' } dataKey={ 'name' } />
         <Bar dataKey={ 'pv' } fill={ '#8884d8' } radius={ 20 }/>
      </BarChart>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimpleBarChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.6.2/dist/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.6.2/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/prop-types@15.6.2/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/recharts@1.4.2/umd/Recharts.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

*Update* - I tried removing the **reversed** prop and just added data with negative values to see if the same inverted bars would happen and the results were the same. So it would seem that when the values are negative and the bars are in the vertical layout, rounded corners will just happen to act this way. Does anyone have any idea what is going on.

*Update* - seems like this was a bug on Recharts side and was fixed in a newer version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Recharts addresses this issue. Once updated, it works fine now

Answer (score 1):

You should specify type in XAxis to be number

```
<BarChart 
  width={600} 
  height={300} 
  data={data} 
  layout="vertical"
  margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}
>
  <XAxis type="number"/>
  <YAxis type="category" dataKey="name" />
  <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
  <Tooltip/>
  <Legend />
  <Bar dataKey="pv" fill="#8884d8" />
  <Bar dataKey="uv" fill="#82ca9d" />
</BarChart>
```

Because the default value of type in XAxis is 'category'.